# Entity Framework works on Local Server but not Remote

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Ok so I have a website that uses ASP.net mvc, the problem I am having is with Entity Framework.  I added all the references and got it to run on my local machine but when I publish it I get the following error.

System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' for the 'System.Data.SqlClient' ADO.NET provider could not be loaded. Make sure the provider assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

I have double checked my references and I have EntityFramework.SqlServer and System.Data both added into my project.  The connection string I use to connect to the data base and declare the service provide is below.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="[dataConnection]" connectionString="Data Source=[ip of host machine];Database=[name];UID=[user];pwd=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Name we just have the name of the data base, this is also used in my web.debug.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="[dataconnection]"
  connectionString="Data Source=.;Database=[name];UID=[user];pwd=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am pretty new to this entire thing and was just handed someone elses code so I am trying to learn on the flow.  This is my first encounter with this so any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem in my integration test assembly (i'm using ms visual studio unit testing framework for this) and i've solved it by adding EF assemblies to deployment items in .testsettings file.

1. I've installed EF 6 alpha using Package Manager Console using: 
   Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre

Here is my app.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

My connection string (i'm setting it in code): `server=.\SIN;initial catalog=IntegrationTests;User ID=user;Password=pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;`

3. I've looked at the EF assembly reference properties to see if they are set to "Copy Local" = True.
   And finally i've checked out TestResults/../Out folder and found that there is no EntityFramework.SqlServer assembly there (SqlProviderServices class resides in it).
4. So i've just added both EF 6 assemblies to my deployment items and now everything is ok
   [image: deployment items]

You can try to copy EntityFramework.SqlServer assembly to your web server directory to see if it works.

Maybe [this link](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6) can be helpful

P.S:

Make sure you don't have a reference to System.Data.Entity, because you'll be using one from GAC. EF 6 Alpha assemblies is not installed in GAC when you install them with Nuget. Target framework should be .NET 4.5.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This worked for me, I think the EntityFrameworkSqlServer.dll was missing when I tried to publish my site.

Answer (score 0):

A question: which EF version?

Check your IIS pool .NET version... It should be the one that points to the .NET version of your published project... The assembly of EF should be in the .NET framework folder under Windows directory (AKA GAC)

Comment: The Version I am using right now is 6.0.0.0.  This is for both EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer

Comment: There is no EF 6.0 - as far as I know... There is, however, IIS 6. Look at the IIS pool that runs your project. The default of IIS 6 is to run .NET 2.0 and that's probably why EF assembly version is not recognized.

Comment: The .net Framework version being run is version 4.0.  The EF framework is actually 6.0 alpha-1.  It released with visual studio 2012 from what I understand.  If I am mistaken in this information let me know, its just what I have been able to find.  Even if all of what I said is true would there be any confliction between .net 4.0 and IIS7?  (IIS7 is what the server is running).  Also the page itself is able to run, it only displays that error when I attempt to use the DB.  Meaning when I try and log in

Comment: Oh, I see... I run EF 4.5 via IIS 7 without any problems (developed it in VS 2012 RC1). Is the EF assembly in your DLL folder? If not, copy it to the GAC.

Comment: I did check the dll folder and they are all there.  I think the server may be out of date so I am attempting to update that and see if it fixes the problem.